# Starting fresh on a blank "theme"

Tags: themes

So, I have been working on a wordpress website for awhile and learned lots of new things.

I used a really nice theme with lots of features.

However over time, I found myself not using any of those features and came up with my own. I even customized the original theme look and feel and there is no original theme look or features on the site any more.

So, I decide to delete the theme and start fresh with a blank "canvas". Of course I have all the custom php files, js, css that I will simply apply.

What is the best way to start with a blank "theme"?

Thanks!

Comment: Rename your theme so it cannot be updated from the original theme and delete everything that you don't need. *best way* will depend on you, not us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have mastered modifying a Wordpress Theme you are ready to create your own. There are many ways to go about this, and it's up to you to figure out what is best for you.

Personally, I like to use a Wordpress Theme framework. My favorite is called Sage (formerly known as Roots). There are other Wordpress Theme Frameworks such as Genisis, Redux, and Underscores.

The reason I like Sage is that is very extensible and allows the use of modern development tools (Composer, Ansible, Vagrant, Capistrano, etc.) to create the theme.

Check it out: [Roots.io](http://roots.io)